# Velocity vs Apache Tiles

Tags: java, spring-mvc, content-management-system, velocity, tiles

What's better?
We are going to start a new web project and it's a question which technology to choose.
Project includes Spring MVC + WebFlow.
Any good/bad experience in support, extending, performance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How do you want compare Tiles with Velocity? - Tiles is a way to compose page fragments, while Veleocity is a more complete template engine, better comparable with JSP than Tiles.

Anyway: I used Spring MVC with Tiles and JSP: It worked greatly, saved a lot of time (toward just using JSP, or JSP with Sitemash), and I did not noticed any performance problems. (But the web application was never used under high load.)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. We should choose how to render views that's the main thing. I also used Spring MVC + Tiles and it worked fine. A new project is coming and customer sggested Velocity. All I need is some arguments why one approach is better than another. What if customer wants kind of CMS to edit site views after app is released without bothering developers?

Comment: @StanislavL The knowlege of an technologie is one of the strongest arguments for it. This is true for devloper, but it is even much more significant for the customer/maintainer. -- If the customer knows one technologie very well, and the project can be done with this technologie, then it better to use the customer's favorite, because it is much easyer for the software developer to lern it too, than for the customer. -- Anyway: Velocity and JSP are not so difficult to lern.

Answer (score 8):

Velocity and Tiles are two different beasts — Tiles is a layout engine and Velocity is a template engine. They do not intersect anywhere in terms of functionality.

From your question I can guess you probably won't be using JSP. That's a smart move. Velocity is one of the template engines out there and it does an absolutely splendid job.

And if you choose to follow the template engine route for your view, then check out [commentit](http://code.google.com/p/commentit). It's a small, simple and fast layout engine I created. It might serve your purpose perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Use **Tiles** if you have some seperate `HTML` files that you want to bring together in a Template (i.e. you have a seperate page for a Header, Footer, Sidebar and you want to bring them together and display them in a sort of Newspaper-like format).

Use **Velocity** if you want to bring dynamic content across from a `Java` backend and inject those values into a full `HTML` page (i.e. you have a `HTML` table to display a selection of Cars, and all of your cars are stored in a Database. Using `JPA`, you could get that Car data out of the database, and into a `List<Car>` maintained in an `EJB` Bean, `Spring @Component`, or similar. Then, using Velocity, you can store that information as the bucket item inside a `Map`, and use the `VTL` mark-up to refer to the key value items in the `Map` so that they can be rendered as part of the `HTML` response.

To achieve the above, Velocity positions itself as an outright Front Controller Servlet, or is wrapped by another MVC framework (i.e. Spring MVC provides a View Resolver which wraps the functionality provided by a Velocity Servlet).

`HTML` requests are directed to the Velocity Servlet or alternative MVC Framework Servlet via `web.xml` configuration. As part of the servlet response, your pre-baked `HTML` view, complete with Velocity `VTL` mark-up, is enriched with `Map` data.

Effectively, and in summary:

**Velocity** competes in the same space as JSP.

**Tiles** is more akin to page transclusion. In the PHP space, Smarty is a popular cousin.

You don't choose between them, but very well could use *both*.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Velocity plugin for Tiles 2.2 so you can use both - with velocity you will access context and build your bricks dynamically like with JSP and tiles will combine your website bricks together. However Tiles is not allowing to do many thigns (at least I haven't discovered them yet) and its documentation is very old and bad compared to for example Spring or JSF one. So you can consider using different technology instead.

I have Tiles references in my currect project because Roo did it for me but right now I'm moving everything to JSF.

Comment: For the benefit of newcomers to these tools who may be reading this question, it is perhaps worth mentioning that JSF is a component-based MVC framework which provides its own templating Engine *and* transclusion mark-up in the form of "Facelets". Conversely, stand-alone Templating Engines are more akin to request-based MVC frameworks which either lack View features of their own or are View technology agnostic. Both Tiles and Velocity compete in the same space as Facelets, because Facelets provides for both requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Use both.  Tiles and Velocity integrate very well and solve different problems.  You can do some Tiles-ish stuff with Velocity's #include and #parse directives, but Tiles does that composition stuff better.